# Tensorflow:Using a trained model in C++

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have a model build in Python using keras and tensorflow. I want to export the model and use it for training in **C++**. I am using **TF1.2** and used the tf.train.export_metagraph to export my graph. I am not exactly sure on how to proceed in using the model in **C++** for training. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Why would want to train the model in C++? Tensorflows core libraries are in c++. I think you mean use the trained model in C++? Once you've trained a model and exported it (assuming you have the .pb file) you use the model for predicting .Theres no way to retrain an exported model.